# Leaks occur when computer lags?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, lag

We have recently discovered that when we run a lot of different processes on our mac while running the instruments to check for leaks, we get some:

`GeneralBlock-16` and `GeneralBlock-64` leaks that happens within ProofReader and UIKit.

None of these leaks can be traced to our own libraries or classes. They only point to apple's own libraries.

We ran the application on the device for 25 minutes and got a total of 96 bytes leaked. And these leaks only occurred when our Mac-mini lagged.

If run NOTHING ELSE but the instruments to check for leaks, we get ZERO leaks.

Has anyone else encountered this? Thoughts?

**Edit:**We're running the application on an iPhone device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

96 bytes?

Just submit it, that's nothing!

Comment: If by "submit" you mean "submit a bug report to Apple" (assuming it's true that the leak can be traced to their code), then I agree.

Comment: Well yea, you should do that but I actually meant submit to the apple store - you're almost never going to remove all the leaks from all the libraries you use and 96 bytes that only leaks when your instruments is stressed is nothing I'd stop releasing an app for. (Though I would look into it a little bit more during the approval process, just in case!)

Comment: Nice!! Sometimes there are false leaks also detected. And as your said 96 bytes is nothing.